# How To Deal With Errors In Express Controller / Service Setup?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I have a challenge where I can't really make a decision on how to deal with HTTP responses / Errors in my services and controllers in my Express API. My goal is to have the services be responsible for one thing only and not deal with HTTP at all. Atleast that's my thought.

I would love some feedback on my approach...

I have added general error middlewares:

```
const errorResponder = (error, req, res, next) => {
  if (error.statusCode && error.message) {
    return res.status(error.statusCode).send(error.message);
  }
  if (error.statusCode) {
    return res.status(error.statusCode).send();
  }
  if (error.message) {
    return res.status(500).send(error.message);
  }
  return next(error); // Forward if above is't triggered
};
const errorFailSafe = (error, req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Fail safe");
  res.status(500).send("Something went wrong, we are digging into it!");
};
```

And then in my controller I unwrap what I need from the req and send to a service. Afterward I send the response back to the client.

```
findUser: async (req,res,next) => {
    const userId = req.params.userId;
    try {
        // Call service
        const user = await UserService.findOne(userId);
        // Send user back to client
        res.status(200).send(user);
    } catch (error) {
        return next(error)
    }
}
```

In my service using Sequelize:

```
findOne: async (userId) => {
  try {
    let user = await db.users.findByPk(userId);
    if (user == null) {
      throw new NotFound("User not found");
    }

    return user;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};
```

The NotFound error is a custom error class extending Error.

```
class NotFound extends Error {
  constructor(message) {
    super(message);
    this.statusCode = 404;
  }
}
module.exports =   NotFound ;
```

Here I kinda break the seperation by having the Service deal with HTTP by calling NotFound.
I could change this so it's the Controller doing the check. Would that be better?

Any feedback would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Yes, the controller should be the only thing that knows about the transport layer. You could have a middleware that's aware of the mapping `NotFound` (business logic error) to 404 (HTTP response status code), rather than letting the latter bleed into the former (e.g. `if (err instanceof NotFound) return res.sendStatus(404)`).

Comment: Makes sense. So the check for the user == nulll is transferred to the controller then?

Comment: No, that's still a business problem - the service would still check for the user and throw an error if not found, but that error would no longer have transport layer concerns baked into it. The error then gets caught and turned into an appropriate response in the controller (or middleware, if you need to extract repetition).

Comment: Okay. So I should remove the transport layer (statusCode) from the NotFound Error Class and check if the Error in my global Error middleware is instanceof NotFound ? :)

Comment: Yes, exactly. That keeps the business logic (did we get a user for that ID?) and the transport logic (what response status code does that mean?) separate and in their appropriate layers.

Comment: Makes sense! Would you use these custom Error Classes in the controller also or just use them in the services?

Comment: Let's say the req.params isn't found and I need to send a 400 request to the client. Would you make a custom error called "BadRequest" and then handle it just like the services? For more consistent error handling. Or is it fine to send the res.status(400).send("User ID not provided") ?

Comment: I'd just respond there, rather than throwing an error from the controller (which adds a layer of indirection for unclear benefit). That said if you're cleaning up a bunch of repetition in the transport layer, there you _could_ have errors with status codes, as they already belong to the appropriate layer (`throw new BadRequest("User ID not provided")`).